# How to configure ADAL authentication prompt with the client_secret parameter

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, adal

When I configure an Authentication prompt to connect to Azure AD:

```
        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);

        var result = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource (using the clientID), 
                     clientId, 
                     redirectUri,
                     new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.SelectAccount))
                     .Result;
```

It fails with the error:

> "AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the following parameter:
>   'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'"

Should a client_secret need to be configured when we are connecting by user, not client, credentials and if so how does it need to be configured?

Comment: Try to navigate to your AD App in the portal -> Authentication -> Default client type -> set it to Yes.

Comment: The Default Client Type is set to Yes.

Comment: Also select the `Access tokens` and `ID tokens` of `Implicit grant`.

Comment: I've enabled Id tokens and Implicit Grant however I still get the error.

Comment: The `clientId` and `resource` are the same? The resource should be like`https://graph.microsoft.com/` which you request the token for.

Comment: I tried https://graph.microsoft.com/ as the resource however I still received the error about the client_secret missing.

Comment: Make sure your app registration has: `allowPublicClient: true`, `oauth2AllowImplicitFlow: true` and add native type app instead of webapp/web api.

Comment: Thanks Joy, @JoeyCai. The last piece missing was to set the Reply Url to  "native type app" instead of Web API. It works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, client_secret needn't to be configured when we are connecting by user.

[image]

Just add a desktop+devices platform with a redirect url provided or use the default one. I am using the default one.

[image]

Comment: There will be some delay after changing the configuration.